# Convert string array to date, filter it and convert back to string

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, momentjs

It may be a newbie `javascript` question but I get crazy with dates ...

I have this `array` of strings and the two strings `from` and `to`:

```
var arr = ['2015-01-20','2015-02-14','2015-02-17','2015-03-06']

var from = '2015-02-01';
var to   = '2015-03-01';
```

I want to obtain:

```
['2015-02-14','2015-02-17']
```

I tried using `underscore.js` and `momentjs` but this fails:

```
_.filter(arr, function(x){
    return moment(x,'YYYY-MM-DD').isBetween(moment(from,'YYYY-MM-DD'), moment(to,'YYYY-MM-DD'))
});
```

Giving an empty result `[]` ...
How could I solve this problem and what would be the more concise way to get the wanted result?

Comment: `.isBetween(moment(from,'YYYY-MM-DD'), moment(to,'YYYY-MM-DD'))`  the second one should be `to`

Comment: yes this is true! and corrected!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter` the array and then use moment's `inBetween` function.

```
arr.filter(function(date) {
    return moment(date).isBetween(from,to);
});
```

Source: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [the docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/), the method will just accept the string in that format (no need to create moment objects).

also you have a typo where its between both from and from. (needs to be from and to)

```
arr.filter(function(x) {
    return moment(x).isBetween(from, to);
});
```

Comment: exactly, he's using from and from